# Open attachments in new tab/window

Tags: attachments, links

I'm trying to make every attachment link open in a new tab/window but checking the 'Open link in a new tab' checkbox in the post editor or adding target="_blank" manually doesn't seem to work. Links always open in the same window.

According to [this topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-removing-target-attributes) the editor is stripping the target attribute.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't have a blank install have you tried disabling all your active plugins to see if it might be a conflict?

If you can set the links to open in a new window when no plugins are active then activate one plugin at a time to figure out the culprit.

Also check if your plugins, themes, wordpress are in need of updates.

Don't forget to backup first.

Answer (score 0):

Be wary with the thread you referenced as it is over 6 years old! WordPress has changed significantly since then!

In addition to what the previous answered suggested, also check your browser to ensure that you can open up in new tabs/windows. Will this happen on another site? You may have hit some setting that always opens up a new window in the current window (i.e., the browser is overriding the attribute).